# How to show RTMP live stream in moviePlayer?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I am struggling to show RTMP live stream using moviePlayer.

I've tried

```
        var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(directory: NSDocumentDirectory, nil, true).
        var documentsDirectory = NSString[paths, objectAtIndex:0]
        var pathVideo = NSString(documentsDirectory, stringByAppendingPathComponent: "")
        var movieUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: pathVideo)

        self.moviePlayer .contentURL(movieUrl)!

        self.moviePlayer .play()
```

But seems like even I'm not using it as I should, or it's not possible to be done using moviePlayer.
Any other solution if this isn't supposed to work?

Comment: When I made such a RTMP player, there was no direct way to play RTMP stream in iOS SDK, so I implemented a handmade demuxer for it. It seems the situation has not changed.

Comment: @findall so basically what I can do is to find already created library in Obj-C and implement it in my Swift code, right? Since, this is pretty weird in my opinion when I know this can work using Obj-C but not using Swift in the same xcode version.